# Can not be deleted data from firebase if internet service is off in fFutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching data from firebase collection..and showing all transaction in Transactioncard..In transaction card's list tile I have placed on tap for delete record

Just now I noticed that it deletes even when net is off...than how is it possible?

here I don't want to allow to delete if internet is not on...

here is my code

```
return TransactionCard(
                          ontap: () async {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    //backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                    content: Text('Are u sure to delete'),
                                    actions: [
                                      TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () async {
                                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                .collection('users')
                                                .doc(widget.loggeduser.userid)
                                                .collection('expenses')
                                                .doc(transactionlist[index]
                                                    ['id'])
                                                .delete().then((value) => Navigator.pop(
                                                context)).then((value) => print('Deleted'));

                                          },
                                          child: Text('yes')),
                                      TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          },
                                          child: Text('No'))
                                    ],
                                  );
                                });
                          },
                          amount: trans.amount.toStringAsFixed(2),
                          datetime: trans.date.toString(),
                          paymentby: trans.paymentmode,
                          category: trans.category.title,
                          categoryicon: trans.category.iconurl,
                          isexpense: trans.isexpense,
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the internet by using [connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package
so you can disable delete button if there is no internet

Your code will be like this:

```
YourAppState{
    ConnectivityResult _connectionStatus = ConnectivityResult.none;
    final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
    late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _connectivitySubscription_connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);
  }

   Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
     setState(() {
       _connectionStatus = result;
     });
      if (_connectionStatus.toString() == "ConnectivityResult.none") {
         navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
        }
    }
```

}

Then up your delete button write this condition

```
if(_connectionStatus.toString() != "ConnectivityResult.none")
```

now if there is no internet connection the button will not appear